# cant input float number in java

Tags: java

i am new in java. i use Eclipes java editor. When i want to get user input as a float or double number it's give error as

Enter your number:
3.1414

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

```
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at myaaa.SubClass1.azizul(SubClass1.java:11)
at myaaa.NewLife.main(NewLife.java:8)
```

what should i do. plz help. i am using windows 8.1. thanks

Comment: Can you show us your code? I appreciate that you're new.

Comment: Since you're using nextDouble(), did you remember to cast it to a float?

    `(float)sc.nextDouble();`

Comment: It's likely that you're not parsing your input. Make sure you're declaring your float variable as such, and that the user input is also a float.

Answer (score 2):

try with comma, your input has to be according to the locale setting for successfull converting to float or double

Comment: If the separator between units and tenths (the decimal separator) is a comma, the period is assumed to be the separator between groups of three digits: 1.234.567,8 is more than one million, with 8 tenths. (This is derived from your Locale setting.) A group of four digits (1414) results in that exception.

Answer (score 2):

You may ensure that the period (.) is accepted as the decimal separator by

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
scanner.useLocale( Locale.US );
double d = scanner.nextDouble();
System.out.println( d < 10);
```

Now, 3.1414 is accepted as a number less than 10, and 3,123 is accepted as a number greater than three thousand.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use this code, which is better to get what you need until it's valid

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean isDataValid = false;

do {
    System.out.println("Enter a float number: ");
    try {
        float yourNumber = Float.parseFloat(scan.next()); 
        isDataValid = true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println ("The entered number is not a float, try again:");
        isDataValid = false;
    }           
}while (!isDataValid);
```

Comment: It might just be an example, but what is the point in reading the user input if the variable scope of `yourNumber` is limited to the `try` block?

Comment: it's just example. you can change it to make whatever you like.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
         float yourNumber = Float.parseFloat(scan.next()); 
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e){
         System.out.println ("not a float");
    }
```

Comment: `scan.next()` returns a `String`, so it won't work. `Float.parseFloat(scan.next())` will work, though it's a lot simpler just using `scan.nextFloat()` instead...

Comment: Just so we're clear, `scan.next()` returns a String and would throw the same exception the OP is getting.

Comment: Yup, `Scanner.next()` returns a `String` and not a `float`. It says so in the [documentation you linked](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()).

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor ...so?

Comment: I want him to see the documentation, also, I updated my answer

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor The link should probably be in your answer, then. It's more visible that way.

Comment: @AzizulSheikh you can vote up and mark it's the answer you been looking for